# How to create a Calc Add-in : write .oxt code

Tags: python, spreadsheet, libreoffice-calc, libreoffice-basic

I want to create a .oxt Add-in for LibreOffice (/ OpenOffice) which can do row-column selection like this :

[image]

these are the results of a little chess tournament for 4 players : when selecting a row (*) i want the column with the same player name become selected also .. while clicking with the mouse, this can be done by holding the Ctrl-key when clicking the concerning column head letter : see image .. but how can this be done programmatically ?  I guess some simple .oxt file can be made, but how ? Btw. would like to use Python for it and maybe Basic.

*) by clicking the most left row number cell (i use LibreOffice Calc on Linux)

this seems a rather specific coding topic .. i found a bit info about this, but not much .. documentation is abstract and lacks examples, eg. https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Add-In

can anyone point me to a useful source ?

Comment: Perhaps [**this discussion**](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?p=200551#p200551) will give you a useful idea ([**Lupp's demonstration**](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/how-can-calc-be-set-to-highlight-the-row-of-the-active-cell/29017/6?u=johnsun) in the last post is very close to the problem you described). By the way, wrapping this solution in a separate extension does not make sense (IMHO) - use [**this advice Zizi64**](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?p=200651#p200651)

Comment: @JohnSUN indeed you point to great info. I have to study it, maybe some macro will do also .. thanks !